# How do I tell Gaia to cache loaded swf files?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, frameworks, gaia

I used Gaia framework to build a self-scrolling slideshow. There are only 4 pages in all, but I have realized to my dismay that each of these pages are requested over and over from the server. If you leave the page open and the animation goes by itself, that can clobber our server.

What can I do to prevent this? I wonder if there is a way of writing a URLRequest so the pragma header can tell the browser to use the swf from its cache rather than requesting it again?

Note that I am not using SWFaddress so the requests are going to the same URI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:
http://www.elevation-inc.com/dev/jeff/gaiacache/

"Core idea is based on adding a new flow, Gaia.CACHE. When caching pages/swfs, it is very important to garbage collect within those assets. Pages will never be destroyed, but will rather rely on calling transitionIn and transitionOut - potentially several times in a browsing session."

I think it might solve your problem.

Comment: Link to the Gaia forum on this topic: http://www.gaiaflashframework.com/index.php/topic,2501.0.html